# Умножение матриц с помощью дружественных функций

Tags: c++, массивы, динамические-массивы, dynamic, дружественная-функция

Не пойму где находиться ошибка, делал программу перемножение двух матриц одинаковых(2х2 3х3 и т.д.) так вот. Почему на выходе где-то два числа теряются в массиве "с"? В самой функции выводит ок `matr operator*(matr&a,matr&b)` , а в этой когда передаю уже на вывод `void matr:: vivod()` что-то происходит, наверное утечка, но причин не найду, подскажите.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
class matr
{
private:
    double **pf;
    int n,m;
public:
    void vvod();
    void vivod();
    friend matr operator*(matr&a,matr&b);
};
void matr:: vvod()
{
    cout << "Enter N = ";
    cin  >> n;
    cout << "Enter M = ";
    cin  >> m;
    pf=new double*[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        pf[i]=new double[m];
        for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
        {
            cout << "Enter pf ["<< i<<"] [" << j << "]";
            cin  >> pf[i][j];
            cout << "pf ["<< i<<"] [" << j << "] = " <<pf[i][j] << endl;
        }
    }
}
void matr:: vivod()
{
   for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
        for(int l=0; l<m; l++)
        {
            cout << "In vivod [ "<< i<<" ] [ " << l << " ] = " <<pf[i][l] << endl;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    matr q,w;
    q.vvod();
    w.vvod();
    matr c;
    c=q*w;
    c.vivod();
    return 0;
}
matr operator*(matr&a,matr&b)
{
    int s;
    matr v;
    v.n=a.n;
    v.m=a.m;
    if(a.n==b.n && a.m==b.m)
    {
        v.pf=new double*[v.n];
        for(int i=0;i<v.n; i++)
        {
            for(int l=0; l<v.n; l++)
                {
                    s=0;
                    v.pf[i] = new double[v.m];
                    for(int j=0; j<v.m; j++)
                        {
                           v.pf[i][l]+= a.pf[i][j] * b.pf[j][l];
                        }
                            cout << "v.pf [ "<< i << " ] [ "<< l <<  " ] = " << v.pf[i][l]<< endl;
                }
        }

    }
    return v;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

- Память, выделенную `new double` никто не освобождает (имеет смысл вместо голых указателей использовать `vector` или хотя бы умные указатели).
- Не определены конструкторы копирования и операторы присваивания (перемещения).
- Внутри `operator*` цикл `for(int l=0; l<v.n; l++)` будет на каждой итерации перетирать значение `v.pf[i]` с предыдущей итерации (опять же позволяя памяти утекать).

Comment: Зачем, это же не классы.
За память, щас попробую.

Comment: Что значит "зачем"? Если ее не освобождать, то она будет утекать. В С/С++ за освобождение памяти всегда отвечает программист. А при копировании классов туда-сюда вообще выйдет винегрет.